# Why do some movies have photoshopped pictures of the 'family'

Tags: props

I've seen it on quite a few movies where they show pictures of the family in some past gathering or with friends but usually they are photoshopped in some background or their faces are shopped onto someone's elses body and not that well made.

If you asked me what movies I woudln't remember but I've seen it more than 3 times, usually in comedies. I don't think it's for comedic purposes because that would sort of be a 4th wall joke. And I'm sure for the budget of a semi big Hollywood movie they would at least get someone who is good at Photoshop.

Why does it look like that?

Comment: Are you asking why they have photos our why they have badly Photoshopped photos? The latter is fairly unanswerable - on the order of why do plots suck and why special effects are terrible.

Comment: Some people just aren't good at photoshop?

Comment: I would say some of the effect is caused by the fact that the photos are obviously photoshopped no matter how well done they are because we know the family as fake therefore we know the photo is fake. While this isn't quite what you're talking about it will still make the photo look fake especially when we're looking for fake photos

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to answer without specific examples to look at, but maybe they're taking actual older pictures of the actors and photoshopping them together so that it looks like a photo taken years ago when all of the characters were much younger.

Comment: Yeah, I would say that they edit pictures of the characters' pasts because they don't have the foresight to take the photgraphs years or decades before they decide to make the movie.